# Largest amount of chemical in tank and how fast it is reached?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

I have a tank filled with $500\,\rm L$ of air and new polluted air is coming in with $30\,\rm L/min$ with $1\,\rm L$ of chemical ($0.88\,\rm mol$). And from tank is being sucked out 30l/min air with concentration of $y(t)$.

Now I have to make DY, which I guess would be

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 30\,\mathrm{L/min} \cdot \frac{0.88}{30\,\mathrm{L/min}} - 30\,\mathrm{L/min} \cdot y(t)$$

And from here I would get something like

$$y = \text{somehing} + Ce^\text{something}$$

But to get to this point I have to use the limit according to the change of time when it is approaching $0$, and this would give me definition of derivative to the other side. I also know that in the beginning $y(t) = 0$ and $t = 0$.

I've also tried population model for this:

$$\Delta y = 30\,\mathrm{L/min} \cdot y \cdot \Delta t - 30\,\mathrm{L/min} \cdot y \cdot \Delta t + 1\,\mathrm{L(or\,0.88\,mol)} \cdot \Delta t$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the amount of pollutant in the tank be $p(t)$ moles. So the tank gains pollutant at the rate of $0.88\,\rm mol$ per min and loses it at the rate of $\frac{30}{500}p(t)$. So

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = 0.88-\frac{30}{500}p(t)$$

with $p(0)=0$.

Note that this equation is change in amount of pollutant not the change in concentration as you have.

Now the amount of chemical will increase until a steady state is achieved which is when $\frac{dp}{dt}=0$, so eventually $$p_\mathrm{max}=0.88 \cdot \frac{500}{30}\,\rm mol$$